# sliding of divs over other divs on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a group of div with id "side-panel-options"

[image]

The effect i want is

[image]

i have tried shuffling the positions in every possible logical way "absolute","relative", "static" etc, but to no avail.

my present css is

```
#side-panel-option
{
    background: rgba(209,209,209,1);
    height : 75px;
    width : 150px;
    margin-top : 5px;
    z-index : 0;
}
```

and

```
#side-panel-option:hover
{
    background: rgba(209,209,209,1);
    height : 100px;
    width : 200px;
    position : static;
    margin-top : 5px;
    z-index : 10;
}
```

Please suggest what should i try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try scaling

```
transform: scale(value);
```

just add this in the hover tag.

Comment: it doesnt have any unit. it can be integer or decimal number.

Answer (score 3):

Try scaling:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.wrapper .item {
  background: rgba(209,209,209,1);
  height : 75px;
  width : 150px;
  margin-top : 5px;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #000;
}

.wrapper .item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You do realize there may be only one html element with any given id in a page?

Please also show the html. E.g. inline elements don't take width and height.

If your html looks like

```
<div id="sidepanel-options">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
</div>
```

that's ok, even though in a semantic sense it would be better to use a list, either ordererd list or unordered list, depending on the character of your content.

But if it looks like

```
<div>
  <div id="sidepanel-options">Item 1</div>
  <div id="sidepanel-options">Item 2</div>
  <div id="sidepanel-options">Item 3</div>
  <div id="sidepanel-options">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

that's not okay because you are using duplicate ids where every given id may be used only once in the whole html page.

For the first example the css would look somewhat like the following:

```
#sidepanel-options > div {
  background-color: rgba(209,209,209,1);
  height : 75px;
  margin-top : 5px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  width : 150px;
}
#sidepanel-options > div:hover {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px; 
}
```

This solution would still push the lower divs 25px to the bottom because of the increase in the hovered div's height. To avoid that, you can use the transform: scale(value) rule noted above, but that one also increase the size of the contents of the div (which may not be what you want).

Please also note that there is no need to repeat the same rules in the :hover-selector if you have identical rules already defined for the non-hovered state.

Comment: Why? She seems to have a list of blocks that she wants to apply the mouseover behaviour to. Nonetheless the css rules she gives us are id-based.

Comment: You seem to have no clue, @MegaMind.

Comment: Funny how none of the downvoters found it useful to at least explain what they dislike here. FU!